# Is there a wey to use a dictionary object as data in echarts?

Tags: echarts

I'm using echarts to plot my data. Then I have two data which has different time(which is X axis),and I want to plot them in one picture. But I found that echart's data just can be a array,So this two data's value will not plot right as their real time.
So my questions is that can echarts use a dictionary data?which use time as key.Then the two data will plot at right time.

Answer (score 0):

try using the type 'time' on xAxis. See also the new way to pass data to the chart using dataset:

```
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

// format with arrays:
var source = [  
    ['2019-08-28T07:01:00+02:00', 127.7],
    ['2019-08-28T07:02:00+02:00', 148.0],
    ['2019-08-28T07:03:00+02:00', 1180.4],
    ['2019-08-28T07:04:00+02:00', 117.9]
]


// format with objects:
// var source = [   
//    { datetime: '2019-08-28T07:01:00+02:00', value: 127.7 },
//    { datetime: '2019-08-28T07:02:00+02:00', value: 148.0 },
//    { datetime: '2019-08-28T07:03:00+02:00', value: 1180.4 },
//    { datetime: '2019-08-28T07:04:00+02:00', value: 117.9 }
// ];

option = {
    dataset: {
        dimensions: ['datetime', 'value'],
        source: source
    },  
    xAxis: {
        type: 'time'
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'series1',
        type: 'line',
    }]
}

myChart.setOption(option);
```